# How to work with specific elements of JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, response

I have a JSON responsee:

```
{  
   "errorMessage":0,
   "comments":[  
      {  
         "commentId":37,
         "name":"name",
         "comment":"zxcasdqwerty",
         "timestamp":1460027788,
         "typeOfUser":1,
         "appropriate":0,
         "inappropriate":0,
         "allreadySetApproval":0
      },
      {  
         "commentId":36,
         "name":"name",
         "comment":"123",
         "timestamp":1460027777,        
         "typeOfUser":1,
         "appropriate":0,
         "inappropriate":0,
         "allreadySetApproval":0
      }
   ]
}
```

So I have upvote/downvote on comments look alike system.
This is how it looks temporary: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdBSx.jpg.

So what I'm actually trying to achieve is whenever I click on the green or red circle I want to access commentId of comments and use/send it to server.
Something like this:

```
var data = {commentId: idOfComment, typeOfUser: typeOfUser, approvalType: 1 };
                    dataservice.setApprovalOnEventComments(document.cookie.substring(12), data, function () {

                    });
```

I did this:  `var idOfComment = res.comments[i].commentId;`but that only gives me first commentId from the comments because I have a for loop that gives me all the comments.

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.comments.length; i++) {
                var text = res.comments[i].comment;
}
```

More of the code : http://pastebin.com/0XEQywcY

Comment: how does your clickhandler look like?

Comment: include some more code.

Comment: Post the code that create the list and relative html

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0XEQywcY Here is more of the code

Comment: What's the problem? So far I've read a message which says "I want...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass the comment ID to the onclick function.

```
likeComment = function ( commentid ) {

    var data = {commentId: commentid, typeOfUser: typeOfUser, approvalType: 1 };
    dataservice.setApprovalOnEventComments(document.cookie.substring(12), data, function () {

    });
};
```

And add it to your html.

```
'<a href="#"><img onclick="likeComment('+ idOfComment  +')"  title="like" class="img-responsive img-circle" src="../../images/my_icon_test_green.png"/></a>' +
```